# bind a JSON value to a Scala class using play

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a fairly complicated form that lets the user select some drop down values and input text in input boxes etc.

The form is essentially a 'Advanced Search' type form.

```
def search = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    val sR = request.body.validate[SearchRequest]
    sR.fold(
      errors => {
        BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "KO", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors)))
      },
      searchRequest => {
        Logger.debug(s"searchRequest is $searchRequest")
        val sr = SearchResults(10)
        Ok(Json.toJson(sr))
      }
    )
  }
```

Say I have a drop down list that has the following values:

```
IsGreaThan
IsLessThan
EqualTo
```

My SearchRequest looks like:

```
case class SearchRequest(operator: String)
```

But I don't want the user to potentially send bad data i.e. a string other than 'IsGreaterThan', 'IsLessThan' etc.

How can I make it strongly typed when the JSON binds to the SearchRequest object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a `Reads` instance for an enumerated type; i.e.:

**Declare a specific `SearchOperator` enum:**

```
object SearchOperator extends Enumeration {
  type SearchOperator = Value

  val IsGreaThan = Value("IsGreaThan")
  val IsLessThan = Value("IsLessThan")
  val EqualTo = Value("EqualTo")
}
```

**Use it in the `SearchRequest` case class:**

```
case class SearchRequest(lhs: Int, operator: SearchOperator, rhs:Int)
```

**Define how to read it:**

```
object SearchRequestJson {
  implicit val soReads = Reads.enumNameReads(SearchOperator)
  implicit val srReads = Json.reads[SearchRequest]
}
```

The key thing being the [`Reads.enumNameReads`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads$@enumNameReads[E%3C:Enumeration](enum:E):play.api.libs.json.Reads[E#Value]) function which was added to Play in version 2.4, and saves a heap of boilerplate for your situation.

Now, if I submit an illegal value as part of the search request:

```
{ "lhs": 42, "operator": "NotEqualTo", "rhs": 44 }
```

I get a:

```
JsError(
  List(
    (/operator, List(
      ValidationError(
        List(error.expected.enumstring),
        WrappedArray()
      )
    ))
  )
)
```